# Android view beyond the basic TextView, ImageView, ListView etc

Tags: android-view, android, android-custom-view

so I have been learning Android Development and so far I have the basic idea of the Android Framework and proficient with Java so I have no trouble creating basic Applications

 
But so far, Im only so good as one would be with html+php in the WebDev world.

My question is, now what? Where should I look to create more feature rich apps? For example in webdevelopment, if I wanted a cool [little callender widget](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html), I can google `jQuery callender` and a get a lot of cool premade widgets. Similary, if I wanted something facy in android, where should I look at? Are there any resources out there which provide some cool things like this?

To be more clear, [here is a page from the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html) on some of the design principles.
How would you create UI something like this:
[image]
Or some layout like this:
[image]
Or some drag and drop features with that white outline as the shadow like this
[image]
Or some dynamic layout like this
[image]

---

**Are there any resources or websites which provides a guide to create things like these just like there are website show jQuery widgets in web development** [I've come across one site](http://www.androidviews.net/) but this is only one... im pretty sure I am looking in the wrong location

Comment: This question is not in the scope of the SO community. Please read the guidelines to asking questions.

Comment: All im asking is for a link or two

Comment: Which is outside the scope of this community. If you have specific programming questions, then ask away. But asking for opinions about websites that have pre-made code snippets is something you should be seeking on Google. Or the samples section of the sdk.

Comment: @SQLiteNoob ...Please move on to other questions. If it's really bothering your life you may flag my question

Comment: @Krimson, I provided a link in my answer to the Android API Guide to creating your own custom view. It should help you out as it is what you want to do, creating these "feature rich ui elements."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: you have to implement these design elements yourself by extending the `View` class or the subclasses such as `TextView` or `ListView`. After extending these, you add your own animations, characteristics, etc.

As you were asking for a link, [here is one to the `Creating a View Class` website on Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).

Complex views such as the contact list with pictures, text, notifications, animations, etc. can be combinations of multiple views and require a lot of coding but the above link is how they are made.

Best of luck! Don't let the SO guideline police stop you!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for leading me into the right direction! Definitely helps! Cheers!

Comment: just saw the edit!, Thought the same about implementing these complex things would require a lot of coding!

Comment: It can be done. If you search around [Google], there are probably some libraries that will give you premade elements that you can combine together to your bidding.